# How can I parse YAML into multiple compose.yaml based on the value of a key with python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm parsing YAML and break it into multidifferent YAML file. I use constructor of PyYAML to achieve it, but the effect is poor.

This is a part of my project, I need to parse and split into multiple different  yaml files  based on the value of a key in a yaml file I receive.

yaml file I receive looks like this

```
testname: testname
testall:
    test1:
        name: name1
        location: 0
    test2: 
        name: name2
        location: 2
    test3: 
        name: name3
        location: 0
    test4: 
        name: name4
        location: 2
    ...
locations:
    - 0
    - 2
    - ...
```

I want to parse it and split by device like the following:

```
# location0.yaml
testname:test
tests:
    test1:
        name:test1
        location:0
    test3: 
        name: test3
        location: 0
```

```
# location2.yaml
testname:test
tests:
    test2:
        name:test2
        location:0
    test4: 
        name: test4
        location: 0
```

How to parse like above form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can do this with PyYAML, you would have to restrict
yourself to YAML 1.1. For this kind of read-modify-write you should
use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). Not
only does that support YAML 1.2, it also preserves any comments, tags
and anchor names in case they occur in your source and can preserve
quotes around scalars, literal and folded style, etc. if you need that.

Also note that your output is invalid YAML, you cannot have a
multi-line plain (i.e. unquoted) scalar be the key of (block style)
mapping. You would have to write:

```
"testname:test
tests":
```

but I assume you meant that to be two keys for the root level mapping:

```
testname: test
tests:
```

---

Assuming your input is in `input.yaml`:

```
testname: testname
testall:
    test1:
        name: name1    # this is just the first name
        location: 0
    test2: 
        name: "name2"  # quotes added for demo purposes
        location: 2
    test3: 
        name: name3    # as this has the same location as name1 
        location: 0    # these should be together
    test4: 
        name: name4    # and this one goes with name2
        location: 2
locations:
    - 0
    - 2
```

you can do:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.yaml')


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=4)  # this matches your input
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(in_file)

for loc in data['locations']:
    out_name = f'location{loc}.yaml'
    tests = {}
    d = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(dict(testname="test", tests=tests))
    d.yaml_set_start_comment(out_name)
    testall = data['testall']
    for test in testall:
        if loc == testall[test]['location']:
           tests[test] = testall[test]
           tests[test]['location'] = 0
    # since you set location to zero and this affects data, make sure to remove 
    # the items. This will prevent things from going wrong in case the
    # locations sequence does have zero, but not as its first number
    for key in tests:
         del testall[key]
    yaml.dump(d, Path(out_name))
```

which gives `location0.yaml`:

```
# location0.yaml
testname: test
tests:
    test1:
        name: name1    # this is just the first name
        location: 0
    test3:
        name: name3    # as this has the same location as name1 
        location: 0    # these should be together
```

and `location2.yaml`:

```
# location2.yaml
testname: test
tests:
    test2:
        name: "name2"  # quotes added for demo purposes
        location: 0
    test4:
        name: name4    # and this one goes with name2
        location: 0
```

Comment: thank you very much! I have another question. if I want to use DoubleQuotedScalarString(connect(while is a is a CommentedMap instance)), the result is "ordereddict([('test1', 10), ('test2', 'abc'), ('test3', 'def')])"
how to clear "ordereddict" and keep the key-value pairs in order? using dict can clear it but key-value pair be disordered.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it, by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the answer. That way others know that it is answered. As for the question in your comment, I am not sure what you by clear ordereddict and kep the key-value pairs in order. You can copy the keys-value pairs to a dict, which is insertion ordered in Python 3.7 (3.6?), but lacks several features from a full ordereddict.